# MariaDB/MySQL Connector/C insert is producing confusing error (C++ on Raspbian)

Tags: c++, mysql, raspberry-pi, raspbian, mysql-connector-c

After some struggling, I was able to get the MariaDB/MySQL libraries linked up to my development environment on the RPi-4B (Raspbian/CodeBlocks).

One of my lines seems to be erroring out and I can't quite figure out why:

```
insertString = "INSERT INTO eco_tank_data (eco_id) VALUES ('"+eco_id"')";
```

produces the error:

> error: expected ';' before string constant

Am I missing something here? I feel like I'm completely bombing some syntax which is why I just included this line, but can include the full program if necessary.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bonus quiz. Find any operator between `eco_id` and `"')"` in `eco_id"')"`.

Comment: Thanks (numbskull award here)